# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects” error

Tags: python, concatenation

I keep getting this error I know it has to do with the "option =" line, I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

```
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
pCard1 = deck.deal()
pCard2 = deck.deal()
print "'s cards are :", pCard1, "and", pCard2
dCard1 = deck.deal()
dCard2 = deck.deal()
print "The Dealer's cards are:", dCard1, "and", dCard2
playerTotal = (Card.getCardValue(pCard1) + Card.getCardValue(pCard2))
dealerTotal = (Card.getCardValue(dCard1) + Card.getCardValue(dCard2))
if playerTotal == 21:
    rules(playerTotal,dealerTotal)
if dealerTotal == 21:
    rules(playerTotal,dealerTotal)
option = raw_input("Your total is" + playerTotal + ", Would you like to take a hit or stay?")
if option == "stay" or option == "Stay":
    dealersTurn(dealerTotal)
    rules(playerTotal,dealerTotal)
```

Answer (score 2):

just use str() to convert to string

```
option = raw_input("Your total is" + str(playerTotal) + ", Would you like to take a hit or stay?")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast integers into strings with [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), Python will not do this for you.

```
option = raw_input("Your total is" + str(playerTotal) + ", Would you like to take a hit or stay?")
```

Alternatively, you can use [the string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) (which, bizarrely, is `%` normally the modulus operator) instead of concatenation.

```
option = raw_input("Your total is %d, Would you like to take a hit or stay?" % playerTotal)
```

Which should you use?  Depends.  Formats are good for long messages which can be hard to read with lots of variables stuck in the middle.  They're also good for when you need to massage the variables, such as justifying them or making sure they have a certain number of digits (like turning 0 into 0.00).  Otherwise, use concatenation.